# how to use source in autocomplete in jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

below is the html input

```
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" id="search_data" name="search_data" value=""  data-link="currency_autocomplete.php" >
```

this is the jquery i use for autocomplete

```
$(function() { 
        $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: 'currency_autocomplete.php',
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                return false;}
        })
});
```

the above code is working fine

but i need to update jquery `source:` something like below

```
$(function() { 
        $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: $(this).attr('data-link'),  *** here i need update
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                return false;}
        })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not `.autocomplete` on that context and that's the reason why you can't get `data-link` attribute value. If there is only one element with `.autocomplete` class you could use this

```
source: $(".autocomplete").data('link')
```

Use this for the case you have more elements with class `.autocomplete`

```
$(".autocomplete").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.autocomplete({
        source: $this.data('link'),
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: if there is more input's like auto how i use this ?

Comment: @user475464: I don't see any obvious problem. Maybe you can help me and tell me where is the problem. Is `$this.data('link')` empty? Are you getting any js error?.

Comment: i make an alert inside like this `$(".autocomplete").each(function() { alert('a')` but it not activate this in `$(".autocomplete").each`

Comment: i think its not getting inside `$(".autocomplete").each`

Comment: @user475464: are you executing that inside document ready? If it's not getting inside `$(".autocomplete").each` is because there is no element matching by the time that runs